# SSRS report not displaying in some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, reporting-services

I have recently deployed a report and it is having some trouble displaying in Google Chrome and Firefox, yet works fine in IE.

The report has trouble when drilling down into another report via tablix cell click. The drilled down report is completely blank and doesn't display anything in Chrome or Firefox.

Upon inspecting the HTML for chrome in the blank report I have found that the report displays after clicking the "toggle device mode" button/changing the window size.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: SSRS Reports are designed to be used in Internet Explorer. There are alot of compatibility issues with chrome and firefox such as the calendar controls and print buttons not showing up.

Comment: I believe SSRS 2014 supports Chrome more or less correctly, but as Adam says above, earlier versions do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick fix is to install the IE T[IE Tab for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd). This helps but again has issues with certain things such as the calendar datetime selections. There are known compatibility issues with chrome and SSRS since SSRS is designed to be used by Microsoft's Internet Explorer.

Aside from essentially creating your own custom SSRS modules compatible with Chrome and Firefox in .NET, this isn't something that is a 100%, permanent, guaranteed fix.